# Connecting homomorphism of long exact sequence sends fundamental class to fundamental class of a boundary component

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I have the following homework problem.

> Let $f\colon (M,\partial M)\to (M',\partial M')$ be a map between two
> compact connected oriented $n$-manifolds such that $f\big|\partial M\to \partial
>  M'$ is a homeomorphism. Then $\deg(f)=\pm 1$.

My idea is to use the long exact sequence of the pair $(M,\partial M)$ and $(M',\partial M')$. Since, $f\big|\partial M\to \partial M'$ is a homeomorphism $H_{n-1}(f)\colon H_{n-1}(\partial M)\to H_{n-1}(\partial M')$ is an isomorphism.

Now, ***if $\partial M$ is connected*** then $\partial M'$ is also connected and the connecting homomorphisms $\partial_n\colon H_n(M,\partial M)\to H_{n-1}(\partial M)$, $\partial_n'\colon H_n(M',\partial M')\to H_{n-1}(\partial M')$ send the fundamental classes $[M],[M']$ to the fundamental classes $[\partial M],[\partial M']$, respectively. So, $\partial_n, \partial_n'$ are isomorphisms. Finally, using naturality of connecting homomorphism we can say $H_n(f)\colon H_n(M,\partial M)\to H_n(M',\partial M')$ is an isomorphism. So, we are done in case $\partial M$ is connected.

> But, I don't know how to deal with the case when $\partial M$ is not
> connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the point is that if we decompose the boundary into its components
$$\partial M = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_K
$$
then the image of the homomorphism
$$\partial_n : H_n(M,\partial M) \to H_{n-1}(\partial M) \approx H_{n-1}(B_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus H_{n-1}(B_K)
$$
is an infinite cyclic group, generated by the sum over $k$ of the fundamental class of each component $B_k$ with respect to the induced boundary orientation on $B_k$.

So in the context of your problem, $\partial_n$ and $\partial'_n$ will still be isomorphisms onto their images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, you are saying this $H_n(M,\partial M)\cong \Bbb Z$ and $H_{n-1}(\partial M)\cong \Bbb Z^3$(assuming $k=3$), and if $\partial_n$ is the map $1\mapsto (1,1,1)$ then $\partial_n$ is the isomorphism between $\Bbb Z$ with $\big\{(\ell,\ell,\ell): \ell\in \Bbb Z\big\}$. But, the restriction map $f\big|\partial M\to \partial M'$  induces a map $H_{n-1}(\partial M)\to H_{n-1}(\partial M')$ which may look like this $(1,1,1)\mapsto (+1,-1,+1)$.

Comment: I am struggling why $(1,1,1)\mapsto (+1,-1,+1)$ is not possible? May be first I need to show $H_n(f)\colon H_n(M,\partial M)\to H_n(M', \partial M')$ is non-zero, say multiplication by $p\in \Bbb Z\backslash \{0\}$, and we are giving induced orientation on the boundary components. Is it true then that $f\big|B_i\to B_i'$ induces a map $H_{n-1}(B_i)\to H_{n-1}(B_i')$ which is again multiplication by $p$ for any $i=1,...,k$.

Comment: As far as multiplication by $p$ is concerned, all of the homomorphisms in question are abelian group homomorphisms, hence they are all $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: Ahh! sorry, it is diagram chase:  $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 H_n(M,\partial M) @>\displaystyle\partial_n>> H_{n-1}(\partial M)=\oplus_{i=1}^kH_{n-1}(B_i)\\
@V f_* V V @VV \oplus_{i=1}^k f_{i*} V\\
H_n(M',\partial M') @>>\displaystyle \partial_n'> H_{n-1}(\partial M')=\oplus_{i=1}^kH_{n-1}(B_i')\\
\end{CD}

Let  $$\displaystyle\big(\oplus_{i=1}^k f_{i*}\big)\circ\partial_n\big([M]\big)=\big(\oplus_{i=1}^k f_{i*}\big)\big(\oplus_{i=1}^k[B_i]\big)=\oplus_{i=1}^k\varepsilon_i\cdot [B_i'],$$ where $\varepsilon_i\in \{+1,-1\}$.

Comment: Also,

 $$\partial_n'\circ f_*\big([M]\big)=\partial_n'\big(p\cdot [M']\big)=p\cdot \partial_n'\big( [M']\big)=p\cdot\oplus_{i=1}^k[B_i']=\oplus_{i=1}^kp\cdot[B_i'],$$ for some $p\in \Bbb Z$. Now, commutativity of diagram says, $$\oplus_{i=1}^k\varepsilon_i\cdot [B_i']=\displaystyle\big(\oplus_{i=1}^k f_{i*}\big)\circ\partial_n\big([M]\big)=\partial_n'\circ f_*\big([M]\big)= \oplus_{i=1}^kp\cdot[B_i']$$$$\implies\varepsilon_i=p\text{ for each }i=1,...,k.$$$$\implies \deg f=p\in \{+1,-1\}.$$ **Am I right?**